# Pasting correcting whole paragraph in Microsoft Word and track will show only corrected words

Tags: microsoft-word, tracking

I want to paste corrected paragraphs to Microsoft Word, but I only want to track words that changed, not the deletion of the paragraph and new paragraph that is pasted. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft Word's "Track Changes" feature tracks the actions you do, like inserts and deletions, instead of comparing the underlying text content. Word will see and track that you *deleted* the existing content and *added* a new paragraph when you paste text over existing content (even if it's the same text). You cannot change this behavior in Word, so you have two main options:

- After completing your text corrections, use Word's **Compare** tool (Review tab > Compare) to show only the changed words. This requires having the old and new version as separate files.
- Use a some other [text comparison tool](https://www.google.com/search?q=text%20diff%20tool) to manually compare the text of the updated paragraphs, then only paste the changed words into your Word document.
- Manually complete the text corrections within Word instead of pasting in new paragraphs.

Comment: You are saying not possible :(

Comment: @elections12 Correct, not the way you are expecting. The Compare tool does use the same change tracking workflow (like approving/denying individual changes and history), so I recommend using that if possible, even if it's awkward to keep a second copy